# Better Way to Remove Special Characters - Access SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, special-characters

I'm looking for a way to remove special characters from a field within my Access database. The field has both text and numbers along with dashes, underscores and periods. I want to keep the letters and numbers but remove everything else. There are multiple examples of VB scripts, and some in SQL, but the SQL examples I've seen are very lengthy and do not seem very efficient.

Is there a better way to write a SQL script to remove these characters without having to list each of the special characters such as the below example?

SELECT REPLACE([PolicyID],'-','')
FROM RT_PastDue_Current;

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually manipulating the data and executing code from the context of the MS Access application, then SQL calls can call any public function inside the modules in the MDB.   You could write a cleanup function, then

```
UPDATE Mytable SET MyField=Cleanup(MyField)
```

Other than that, I have yet to encounter any RDBMS database engine that has much advanced string manipulation features beyond the simple Replace you've mentioned.